# Playing sounds in IE7+?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

What's the best way to play sounds without flash in IE7+? I'm specifically targeting IE browsers for this. Is the `<embed />` tag correct? I've never messed with sounds in HTML before.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Comment and not an answer because this uses Flash.  I use [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org) but it relies on a hidden Flash file in order to play in browsers that are not HTML5 compliant.  Not sure if it's possible without HTML5 and Flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `embed` tag.

```
<embed src="file.mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true">
```

Not pretty (you'll probably annoy the piss out of your visitors) but it works.

Comment: Can I control (play, stop, etc.) it via Javascript like with HTML5 audio? Or do I need to remove/create the element for that?

Comment: I want to say that you can (if you remove the hidden attr). I don't think javascript can do it, but I could definitely be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use media player object - as described here

http://www.jakeludington.com/project_studio/20051015_embedding_windows_media_player_wma.html

I cannot help more now - i'v done it once 4 years ago, and don't remember much ( and i belive the change from then to now is not big )